# Autolayout Top space issue

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, autolayout

The following image shows what I have done. View A should have fixed height, View B's height should be flexible. It works fine but when I rotate the device (in landscape), I obtain warning in Xcode.

[image]

What I have done wrong ?

Comment: Issue is with the constrain which I have mentioned with dotted lines. Because, if I remove it and give fixed height to B, everything works without warning..

Comment: Let me try and I will update you @EICaptain

Comment: B's top space assign to A is constant ? What is its priority and why have you given priority?

Comment: @Irfan, I have not given any priority. Yes, it is constant (20 pixels gap between B and A)

Comment: becuase you have given bottom space to view B . in case of landscape  mode you have small height so it is difficult to satisfy all the constraints like 120 height of view A + TOP constraint of VIEW A + Top Constraint to VIew B + Bottom constraint

Comment: suggestion : Remove bottom space to view B and superview

Comment: If you have given height constraint to View A along with other three then it should never give warning. Can you show constraints on both view A and view B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select top constraint of `B` and  from size inspector reduce it's priority by one. Identically it should 1000 and you need to make it 999 and it will solve issue i think.

hope this will help :)

Comment: It worked for me, warning doesn't appear when I move to landscape. Will it create any issue later on ?

Comment: No it will not create issue. There is no warning that means everything is alright..!